# Spark: Efficient way to test if an RDD is empty

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

There is not an `isEmpty` method on RDD's, so what is the most efficient way of testing if an RDD is empty?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`RDD.isEmpty()`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5270) will be part of Spark 1.3.0.

Based on suggestions in [this apache mail-thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201402.mbox/%3CCAKDwOakbF9pop+pN8XzF6iT1OPc383+aWcTf2a6t=rH8srxRLg@mail.gmail.com%3E) and later some comments to this answer, I have done some small local experiments. The best method is using `take(1).length==0`.

```
def isEmpty[T](rdd : RDD[T]) = {
  rdd.take(1).length == 0 
}
```

It should run in `O(1)` except when the RDD is empty, in which case it is linear in the number of partitions.

Thanks to Josh Rosen and Nick Chammas to point me to this.

Note: This fails if the RDD is of type `RDD[Nothing]` e.g. `isEmpty(sc.parallelize(Seq()))`, but this is likely not a problem in real life. `isEmpty(sc.parallelize(Seq[Any]()))` works fine.

---

### Edits:

- **Edit 1:** Added `take(1)==0` method, thanks to comments.

**My original suggestion:** Use `mapPartitions`.

```
def isEmpty[T](rdd : RDD[T]) = {
  rdd.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(!it.hasNext)).reduce(_&&_) 
}
```

It should scale in the number of partitions and is not nearly as clean as `take(1)`. It is however robust to RDD's of type `RDD[Nothing]`.

---

### Experiments:

I used this code for the timings.

```
def time(n : Long, f : (RDD[Long]) => Boolean): Unit = {
  val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(1L to n, numSlices = 100)
  val result = f(rdd)
  printf("Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "   Result: " + result)
}

time(1000000000L, rdd => rdd.take(1).length == 0L)
time(1000000000L, rdd => rdd.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(!it.hasNext)).reduce(_&&_))
time(1000000000L, rdd => rdd.count() == 0L)
time(1000000000L, rdd => rdd.takeSample(true, 1).isEmpty)
time(1000000000L, rdd => rdd.fold(0)(_ + _) == 0L)

time(1L, rdd => rdd.take(1).length == 0L)
time(1L, rdd => rdd.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(!it.hasNext)).reduce(_&&_))
time(1L, rdd => rdd.count() == 0L)
time(1L, rdd => rdd.takeSample(true, 1).isEmpty)
time(1L, rdd => rdd.fold(0)(_ + _) == 0L)

time(0L, rdd => rdd.take(1).length == 0L)
time(0L, rdd => rdd.mapPartitions(it => Iterator(!it.hasNext)).reduce(_&&_))
time(0L, rdd => rdd.count() == 0L)
time(0L, rdd => rdd.takeSample(true, 1).isEmpty)
time(0L, rdd => rdd.fold(0)(_ + _) == 0L)
```

On my local machine with 3 worker cores I got these results

```
Time:    21   Result: false
Time:    75   Result: false
Time:  8664   Result: false
Time: 18266   Result: false
Time: 23836   Result: false

Time:   113   Result: false
Time:   101   Result: false
Time:    68   Result: false
Time:   221   Result: false
Time:    46   Result: false

Time:    79   Result: true
Time:    93   Result: true
Time:    79   Result: true
Time:   100   Result: true
Time:    64   Result: true
```

Comment: Spark recently merged a pull request to add an `isEmpty` method to RDDs: https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4074

Comment: Good news. The pull request actually contained a bug. I've sent a fix in https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4534

Comment: Tobber, isn't it easier and just as fast to do `.take(1)` on the RDD and see if the result is empty?

Comment: @NickChammas. In short yes. There is though a bug when your RDD is of type `RDD[Nothing]`. This is very much an edge-case however, since an `RDD[Nothing]` is practically useless. We actually have a discussion going on, on the second pull request.

Comment: @Tobber what should be the equivalent in Java?

Answer (score 3):

As of [Spark 1.3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5270) the `isEmpty()` is part of the RDD api. A fix that was causing `isEmpty` to fail was later fixed in [Spark 1.4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5744).

For DataFrames you can do:

```
val df: DataFrame = ...
df.rdd.isEmpty()
```

Here is paste of the code right off from the RDD implementation (as of 1.4.1).

```
  /**
   * @note due to complications in the internal implementation, this method will raise an
   * exception if called on an RDD of `Nothing` or `Null`. This may be come up in practice
   * because, for example, the type of `parallelize(Seq())` is `RDD[Nothing]`.
   * (`parallelize(Seq())` should be avoided anyway in favor of `parallelize(Seq[T]())`.)
   * @return true if and only if the RDD contains no elements at all. Note that an RDD
   *         may be empty even when it has at least 1 partition.
   */
  def isEmpty(): Boolean = withScope {
    partitions.length == 0 || take(1).length == 0
  }
```