# spark program to check if a given keyword exists in a huge text file or not

Tags: scala, apache-spark

To find out a given keyword exists in a huge text file or not, I came up wit below two approaches.

Approach1:

```
def keywordExists(line):
   if (line.find(“my_keyword”) > -1):
       return 1
   return 0
lines = sparkContext.textFile(“test_file.txt”);
isExist = lines.map(keywordExists);
sum = isExist.reduce(sum);
print(“Found” if sum>0 else “Not Found”)
```

Approach2:

```
var keyword="my_keyword"
val rdd=sparkContext.textFile("test_file.txt")
val count= rdd.filter(line=>line.contains(keyword)).count
print(“Found” if count>0 else “Not Found”)
```

Main difference is first one using map and then reducing whereas second one is filtering and doing a count.

Could anyone suggest which is efficient.

Comment: both are inefficient, you should stop the search if the keyword was found

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
val wordFound = !rdd.filter(line=>line.contains(keyword)).isEmpty()
```

Benefit: The search can be stopped once 1 occurence of `keyword` was found

see also [Spark: Efficient way to test if an RDD is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454357/spark-efficient-way-to-test-if-an-rdd-is-empty)